Generate test source using Java's annotation processor
I'm using the java annotation processor to generate code based off an annotation in my project, and that is working well. I'm using AbstractProcessor, and writing the output file like this:
Filer filer = processingEnv.getFiler();
JavaFileObject sourceFile = filer.createSourceFile(fullyQualifiedName);
try (Writer writer = sourceFile.openWriter()) {
  javaFile.writeTo(writer);
}

This generates java files in build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main, which is perfect for that use-case.
Now I want to add more code generation, but this time I want to generate code based on src/main/java for use in tests, so the generated source should live in:
build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test

I don't see any options on ProcessingEnvironment or AbstractProcessor to determine which source set to write the generated code to. What is the expected way to generate test code using Java's annotation processor?

The annotation processor will run based on the dependency configuration it is added to, and be contributed to the corresponding generated source output. Based on the information in your question, you probably have this set up using the annotationProcessor configuration, something like
dependencies {
  annotationProcessor project(':my-processor')
}

Instead, use the testAnnotationProcessor configuration to let the processor have access to your test classes, and write to test outputs:
dependencies {
  testAnnotationProcessor project(':my-processor')
}


Hi Colin, thanks for the reply. I want the annotation processor to process annotated classes in src/main/java, and output to a test source set, something like build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/test. I tried using testAnnotationProcessor, but it seemed like the annotation processor was only applied to my test files.

It sounds like you're going to need a custom solution of some kind then - this isn't how annotation processors work (in gradle, or in general). You might have some luck with a custom JavaCompile task run, with options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory set to your own path, to avoid accidentally making the main java compile ingest the generated test sources https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.CompileOptions.html
